# Integral $I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x) \operatorname{Li}_2 (-x)}{x^{3/2}} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, contour-integration

Hello can you please help me solve this integral
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x) \operatorname{Li}_2 (-x)}{x^{3/2}} dx=-\frac{2\pi}{3}(\pi^2+24\ln 2).
$$
I am trying to work through all logarithmic integrals.
Note, the Polylogarithm function is given by $\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)$ and is defined by
$$
\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-x)^k}{k^2}, \ |-x|<1
$$
and can be extended using analytical continuation for $|-x|>1$.  We also know that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \operatorname{Li}_2(-x)=-\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}.
$$Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One, rather straightforward way, is the following:

1. Make the change of variables $x=y^2$ to rewrite the integral as
   $$\mathcal{I}=2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+y^2)\,\operatorname{Li}_2(-y^2)\,dy}{y^2}. $$
2. Integrate by parts to kill the logarithm, using that
   $$\int \frac{\ln(1+y^2)\,dy}{y^2}=2\,\Im \ln(1+iy)-\frac{\ln(1+y^2)}{y}-\pi, \tag{1}$$
   and also the expression for the derivative $\operatorname{Li}_2'(-y^2)=-2\frac{\ln(1+y^2)}{y}$. The constant $\pi$ on the right of (1) is needed to ensure non-divergent (actually, vanishing) boundary contribution at $y=\infty$. We thus find
   $$\mathcal{I}=4\int_0^{\infty}\left(2\,\Im \ln(1+iy)-\frac{\ln(1+y^2)}{y}-\pi\right)\frac{\ln(1+y^2)}{y}dy.\tag{2}$$
3. The antiderivative of (2) [can be expressed in terms of polylogarithms and elementary functions](http://wolfr.am/1lc0LQz). Substituting the bounds, one finally obtains
   $$\boxed{\mathcal{I}=-\frac{2\pi}{3}\Bigl(\pi^2+24\ln 2\Bigr)}$$

Comment: Can you add more to what you did with (2).  All of a sudden the answer is there, but how do you evaluate all the polylogs, what are all the integral results?  And how did you get (1)

Comment: @Jeff Well, we want to kill the dilogarithm by differentiation using integration by parts. The formula (1) is the necessary piece for this: we have $\int uv'=uv-\int u'v$ with $u= \operatorname{Li }_2(-y^2)$ and $v$ to be found. Concerning (2), once you have the antiderivative from somewhere (e.g. Mathematica), it is easy to check that it's correct by differentiation.

Comment: Can you provide more work please?  How did you get the right hand side of (1), I realize you integrated the first equation by parts to obtain $$  \int \frac{\ln(1+y^2) dy}{y^2}$$, but how do you calculate that integral?  And what do you mean once you find the anti-derivative somewhere?  I am looking for a COMPLETE solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff For example, integrating by parts: denote $u=\ln(1+y^2)$, $v=-1/y$, then $$\int \frac{\ln(1+y^2)\,dy}{y^2} =\int udv=uv-\int v du=uv+\int \frac{2dy}{1+y^2}$$

Comment: Thanks.  I get it.  Very clear answer now that I get what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted my contour integration approach because it was too long, but I kept the shorter approach that uses Ramanujan's master theorem.

---

Using the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of two power series and partial fraction decomposition, we find that $$ \begin{align} \ln(1+x) \operatorname{Li}_{2}(-x) &= \small \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} x^{k+2} \sum_{j=0}^{k} \frac{1}{(j+1)^{2}} \frac{1}{k-j+1} \\ &= \small \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} x^{k+2} \sum_{j=0}^{k} \left( \frac{1}{k+2} \frac{1}{(j+1)^{2}}+ \frac{1}{(k+2)^{2}} \frac{1}{j+1} + \frac{1}{(k+2)^{2}} \frac{1}{k-j+1}  \right) \\ &= \small  -x^{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-x)^{k} \left(\frac{1}{k+2}H_{k+1}^{(2)}+\frac{2}{(k+2)^{2}}H_{k+1}  \right) \\&= \small -x^{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-x)^{k}\left(\frac{\frac{\pi^{2}}{6} - \psi_{1}(k+2)}{k+2}+\frac{2\left(\gamma+\psi(k+2) \right)}{(k+2)^{2}} \right) , \end{align}$$ where $H_{k}$ is the $k$th harmonic number, $H_{k}^{(2)}$ is the $k$th [generalized harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers) of order $2$, $\psi(x)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers),  $\psi_{1}(x)$ is the [trigamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function), and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Applying [Ramanujan's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem), we get $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x)\operatorname{Li}_{2}(-x) }{x^{2}} \, x^{\alpha-1} \, \mathrm dx &=  -\Gamma(\alpha) \left(\frac{\frac{\pi^{2}}{6} - \psi_{1}(2- \alpha)}{2- \alpha}+\frac{2\left(\gamma+\psi(2- \alpha) \right)}{(2- \alpha)^{2}} \right) \Gamma(1- \alpha) \\  &= -\frac{\pi}{\sin (\alpha \pi)}\left(\frac{\frac{\pi^{2}}{6} - \psi_{1}(2- \alpha)}{2- \alpha }+\frac{2\left(\gamma+\psi(2- \alpha) \right)}{(2- \alpha)^{2}} \right), \end{align}$$

which holds for $0 < \alpha < 2$.

(For $\alpha =1$, the right side of the equation should be treated as a limit.)

Letting  $\alpha= \frac{3}{2}$, we get $$ \begin{align}  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x)\operatorname{Li}_{2}(-x) }{x^{3/2}} \, \mathrm dx &= \pi \left(\frac{\frac{\pi^{2}}{6} - \psi_{1} \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)}{\frac{1}{2}} +\frac{2 \left(\gamma +\psi \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)  \right)}{\frac{1}{4}}\right) \\ &= \pi \left(\frac{\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}- \frac{\pi^{2}}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}} - \frac{4 \ln 2}{\frac{1}{4}} \right)   \\ &= \pi \left(-\frac{2 \pi^{2}}{3} - 16 \ln 2 \right) \\ &= -\frac{2 \pi}{3} \left(\pi^{2} + 24 \ln 2 \right). \end{align}$$

---

Similarly, Ramanujan's master theorem shows that $$ \small \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x) \operatorname{Li}_{{\color{red}{3}}}(-x)}{x^{2}} \, x^{\alpha-1} \, \mathrm dx =  - \frac{\pi}{\sin (\alpha \pi)} \left(\frac{\zeta(3)+\frac{\psi_{2}(2- \alpha)}{2}}{(2- \alpha)} + \frac{\frac{\pi^{2}}{6} - \psi_{1}(2- \alpha)}{(2-\alpha)^{2}} + \frac{2\left(\gamma +\psi(2 - \alpha)\right)}{(2-\alpha)^{3}} \right).$$

Letting $\alpha= \frac{3}{2}$, we get $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{\ln(1+x) \operatorname{Li}_{3}(-x)}{x^{3/2}} \, \mathrm dx  &= \pi \left(-\frac{6 \zeta(3)}{\frac{1}{2}} - \frac{\frac{\pi^{2}}{3}}{\frac{1}{4}} - \frac{4 \ln 2}{\frac{1}{8}} \right) \\ &= - \frac{4 \pi}{3} \left(9 \zeta(3) + \pi^{2} + 24 \ln 2 \right). \end{align}$$

---

**Appendix**:

$\psi \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) = - \gamma + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{2}{2n+1}\right) = - \gamma + 2 \lim_{N \to \infty} \left(H_{N} - H_{2N} \right) = - \gamma - 2 \ln 2 $

$\psi_{1} \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) =  4 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2}} = 4 (1-2^{-2})\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^{2}}{2}$

$\psi_{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) = -16 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{3}} = -16 (1-2^{-3})\zeta(3) = -14 \zeta(3)$

Comment: Wow! I really like this approach. (+1)

Comment: @KStarGamer Thanks.