# On the dilogarithm integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log^2(1-x) {\rm Li}_2(-x)}{x} \, {\rm d}x $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, special-functions

Let ${\rm Li}_2$ denote the [dilogarithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html). Evaluate the integral

$$\mathcal{J} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log^2(1-x) {\rm Li}_2(-x)}{x} \, {\rm d}x $$

A related question is [this one here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730874/integral-i-int-0-infty-frac-ln1x-li-2-xx3-2-dx). However, there is a problem because

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} {\rm Li}_2(-x) \neq - \frac{\log(1-x)}{x}$$

On the other hand we could expand the $\log^2(1-x)$ in a Taylor series and express that ${\rm Li}_2$ in an integral form and then deal with a harmonic sum , however I am not comfortable with handling double integration.

Any help?

Comment: I suspect another related question is [this one here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591249/on-the-euler-sum-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frach-n4-h-n2n6).

Comment: @ProfessorVector: they are pretty different. This question is about alternating Euler sums with weight $5$, the other question is about a standard Euler sum with weight $12$.

Comment: This is the result: $-4 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-4 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (2)+\frac{\pi ^2 \zeta (3)}{8}+\frac{15 \zeta (5)}{16}-\frac{7}{4} \zeta (3) \log ^2(2)-\frac{1}{15} 2 \log ^5(2)+\frac{1}{9} \pi ^2 \log ^3(2)$

Answer (score 5):

We have
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\log^2(1-x) x^{n-1}\,dx =\frac{d^2}{da^2}\left.\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^a x^{n-1}\,dx\right|_{a=0}=\frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{n}$$
by differentiating Euler's Beta function. Since $\text{Li}_2(-x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n^2}$, the evaluation of $\mathcal{J}$ boils down to the evaluation of two alternating Euler sums with odd weight:
$$\mathcal{J}=\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n\frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{n^3}. \tag{A}$$
Now $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{n^3}=S_{11,3}-S_{2,3} =8\,\zeta(5)-4\,\zeta(2)\,\zeta(3)$ follows from standard results on cubic Euler sums with weight $5$ (Flajolet and Salvy), and by summation by parts the evaluation of $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n^3}$ boils down to the evaluation of $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n^2} = \frac{11}{2}\,\zeta(5)-2\,\zeta(2)\,\zeta(3)$ and 
$$ \mathcal{K}_1 = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{(2n-1)^2}=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\text{Li}_3(x^2)\log(x)}{x^2(1-x^2)}\,dx.\tag{B}$$
If we manage to compute $\mathcal{K}_1$ and 
$$ \mathcal{K}_2 = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_{2n}^2}{n^3},\tag{C} $$
or just $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2(1-x)\text{Li}_2(x^{\color{red}{2}})}{x}\,dx$, we are done.

> This kind of Euler sums have been studied by [Xu, Yang and Zhang](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04923). Page $13$ of [this recent article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03515) proves that $\mathcal{J}$ is a polynomial in $\zeta(2),\zeta(3),\zeta(5),\log(2),\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$.